# How to get the Source of an event in C# when using ItemControl

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio-2010, xaml

This is a Wpf application and I've created 6 images. On the click of each image I want to display a page.
Xaml code is similar to this.

```
 <Controls:ReflectionControl Grid.Row="2">
            <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Path=DashBoardApps}" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" HorizontalAlignment="Center">
                <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                    <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                        <Controls:FishEyeControl />
                    </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
                            <TextBlock x:Name="txtAppName" Text="{Binding Path=ApplicationName}" TextAlignment="Center" Visibility="Hidden" FontSize="7px" Foreground="#eff7ff" />
                            <Image Source="{Binding Path=ApplicationImage}" Height="32" Width="32" MouseLeftButtonDown="Image_MouseLeftButtonDown_1"/>
                        </StackPanel>
                        <DataTemplate.Triggers>
                            <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                                <Setter TargetName="txtAppName" Property="Visibility" Value="Visible" />
                            </Trigger>
                        </DataTemplate.Triggers>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            </ItemsControl>
        </Controls:ReflectionControl>
```

I've associated the event

```
MouseLeftButtonDown
```

to

```
Image_MouseLeftButtonDown_1
```

The cs code:

```
 private void Image_MouseLeftButtonDown_1(object sender, System.Windows.Input.MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {

            UserControl2 uc2 = new UserControl2();
            pageTransitionControl.ShowPage(uc2);
            canvas1.Visibility = System.Windows.Visibility.Hidden;
            //canvas2.Visibility = System.Windows.Visibility.Visible;
            canvas3.Visibility = System.Windows.Visibility.Hidden;

    }
```

I want to identify the source of each event(The image from which the event has been generated) and assign a code similar to the above code. How do I do it?

Comment: There as 6 images in total. Since I'm using ItemsControl I don't know which image exactly has triggered the Event.

Answer (score 3):

In events handlers, **sender** is the object from which the event originated

```
private void Image_MouseLeftButtonDown_1(object sender, ...
```

In your case, you'll have to cast it to `Image` and then you'll have your origin.

Comment: Yes I tried doing it. I found its Source too. I need a value to compare the source to. But couldn't come up with any. Ex: var s=sender as Image. Now I want to know which image. Since I'm using a ItemsConrol here I can't exactly find which image.

Comment: You could add a Dictionary<> bound to your data collections, with the image source as key and the other value (the application name?) as value. You then look up the value corresponding to the Source you extract from the sender.

Answer (score 1):

First parameter of the callback (`sender`) is a reference to the image being clicked. You have to `try` to cast it.

Comment: var s=sender as Image;    s.source="something that i need to compare to"

Comment: Yes. Once you cast it to `Image`, it's up to you to implement any logic.

Answer (score 0):

> There as 6 images in total. Since I'm using ItemsControl I don't know which image exactly has triggered the Event.

Use a Command in combinatino with a Inputbinding on the image and pass to the commandparametr your datacontext.

```
                <Image>
                <Image.InputBindings>
                    <MouseBinding Gesture="LeftClick" Command="{Binding MyCommand}" CommandParameter="{Binding}"/>
                </Image.InputBindings>
            </Image>
```

as commandparamter you will have your item in the itemscontrol